# How to record multidimensional arrays from forms with Vue?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, vue.js

So I've got this sample:

```
<div class="form-item">
  <label for="list-0"><?php _e('List 0', 'test'); ?></label>
  <input name="list[0]" type="text" id="list-0" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-item">
  <input type="checkbox" name="list[0][is-current]" id="list-0-current" value="yes">
  <label for="list-0-current"></label>
</div>
```

What I'd like to have is something like this:

```
list:[
    [value, is_current] // say 'John', yes
    ,[value, is_current] // say 'Francis', false
    ,[value, is_current] // say 'Bob', yes
]
```

In Vue you can use arrays in data:

```
var vueapp = new Vue({
  el: '#form'
  ,data:{
    form:{
      list:[]
      //[...] etc..
```

Then in your fields you simply use `v-model="form.list"` in every fields of the list. But this would only record a flat array, while I need a way to have a multi one. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

Make an Object:

```
 data: {
      form: [{}]
 },
```

If this is your array:

```
list = [
    [value, is_current],
    [value, is_current],
    [value, is_current],
];
```

Then go over this array and add each inner array to the object:

```
  list.forEach(function(element) {
        that.form.push({value: element[0], key: element[1]});
  });
```

See this fiddle for reference:

https://jsfiddle.net/mnd8ojLh/1/

Comment: Values are not predefined in my case: as you can see, they also come from user input

Comment: Yes? This is the same, the filled one is just for example to visualize the fiddle. Where and when you fill it is completely up to you. If it helps you, I have removed the expamle inputs from the answer.